# Multiple StringBuilder.Append calls vs. single .Append with inner string concat

Tags: .net, string, performance, stringbuilder

What is the best practice when using string builders in .NET regarding multiple calls of the .Append method vs. a single call to .Append while concatenating its parameters?

```
sb.Append(name).Append("; ");
```

vs.

```
sb.Append(name + "; ");
```

Is there any performance penalty when using one over the other? The second variant might in some cases be more readable (and is shorter to write).

Will doing such simple string concatenation of short strings nullify the performance/memory gains of using a string builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I did a test appending text using three approaches in a loop 100,000 times.

(1)

```
    text += "Hello" + i.ToString();
```

(2)

```
    sb0.Append("Hello" + i.ToString());
```

(3)

```
    sb1.Append("Hello");
    sb1.Append(i.ToString());
```

The results were (1) took 108,332ms, (2) took 18ms, and (3) took 19ms.

So it turns out that simple concatenation is ever so slightly faster than two successive calls to the string builder. I suspect that was to do with garbage collections and not the actual speed of building the string.

The bottom-line is that you can use string concatenation without any trouble so long as the strings are relatively small.

Comment: Are your results also the same if you vary `"Hello"` in each loop iteration? `name` is not a literal in the OP's question!

Comment: I did change the test to run with the string "I like to pick wild flowers!". It doubled the time for the plain string concatenation, and the others varied fairly little. The surprise was that method two was now slower than method 4. I suspect garbage collection is messing with methods 2 to 4.

Comment: @D.R. - The `String.Format` method. I mentioned it in the comments on your answer.

Comment: I suspect that appending with `+` just isn't a very good idea except for *very* small strings.

Comment: Also you should pre.ToString() all your i's.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is slower than the first one (although, arguably not by much, so if it helps readability, it doesn't hurt). As a rule of thumb: use `string.Format` or `string.Concat` if appropriate, use `StringBuilder` whenever you are appending stuff in a loop.

I've done some performance testing using this approach:

```
var strings = Enumerable.Range(100000, 200000).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    // whatever method

var result = ...; // e.g. sb.ToString();
watch.Stop();

WriteResultToFile(result); // prevent optimizations
Console.WriteLine("Took: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

Results are as follows:

```
// Method 1: 39317ms
str += strings[i] + ", ";

// Method 2: 8ms
sb.Append(strings[i] + ", ");

// Method 3: 2ms
sb.Append(strings[i]);
sb.Append(", ");

// Method 4: 15ms
sb.Append(string.Format("{0}, ", strings[i]));
```

However, if you have a fixed number of strings to concatenate, please us `string.Concat` as it is able to pre-determine the resulting length and therefore is very performant.

Comment: It does not "ruin" the performance. The main hit when appending strings is when you append a string to a massively long string. The intermediate append are two small strings. There is negligible performance loss in this situation.

Comment: Improved the wording.

Comment: Well, `string.Format` for sure is the slowest.

Comment: @knittl - I tested a `String.Format` using my answer's method and it was slower. It took 33ms compared to 18 & 19ms for the other two string builder approaches. It's certainly slower, but nothing overly significant in real life. We're talking 0.15 nano seconds per call.